# Focus inputs on double click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent input focus onclick and focus inputs on double click.

Something like....

```
$('input').click(function) {
    $(this)preventFocus();
});

$('input').dblclick(function) {
    $(this)focus();
});
```

Or maybe I should use an if statement?

Comment: try $(this).blur() instead of $(this)preventFocus()

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?  check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735764/prevent-firing-focus-event-when-clicking-on-div

Comment: Been trying for 2 hours mate :( I'll take a look at that answer, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(  You should try to phrase your questions in terms of 1) this is what I did and 2) this is the problem I'm having.  The code you posted is not valid Javascript so as written you would get a syntax error, which you didn't mention.

Comment: Ok thanks for tips. Will take them into account in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess something like this should work :

```
$('input').on({
    focus: function() {
        if (!$(this).data('disabled')) this.blur()
    },
    dblclick: function() {
        $(this).data('disabled', true);
        this.focus()
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).data('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4YaL/1/)

Comment: Looks good. Tried it with knockout, but obviously something interfering.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" readonly="readonly" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#myInput").dblclick(function(){
   $(this).prop("readonly", false)
});
$("#myInput").blur(function(){
   $(this).prop("readonly", true); 
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/KWuR5/