# Set textfield value without losing the focus

Tags: jquery, focus, textarea, textfield

how can I change the value of a textarea or textfield

// Clean button

```
 $('#textfield').val('');
```

without losing the focus?

I create at the moment an webApp and the smartphone (android) loosing the focus (and the keyboard disappears) when i click on the cleanButton  ... i must click on/in in the textfield again to write further (not good usability :/ )

Any ideas?

BTW.: this `$('#textfield').val('').focus();` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [preventing default](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)?
You need to stop the browser event which will cause the focus to be lost by calling preventDefault on the event parameter in your callback

```
$('[type="button"]').mousedown(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

Also, make sure you capture attach the callback to `mousedown` and not `click` because the focuse will change automatically when `mousedown` is successful.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MTQK/66/)

[Prevent firing focus event when clicking on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735764/prevent-firing-focus-event-when-clicking-on-div)

Answer (score 0):

yes it would not work because in jquery `.focus()` is an event (similar to `.click()` while in JS `.focus()` puts focus on the desired element.

i know how to do it with javascript, try this:

```
var clrBtn = $('#cleanButton'); //from jQuery to JavaScript
$('#cleanButton').val('');
clrBtn.focus(); // here the focus goes to clnBtn (JS function)
```