# How to prevent the popover div for hiding on clicking inside it for twitter bootstrap "dismissible popover"(data-trigger="focus")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a a dismissible popover(data-trigger="focus") with a text box inside it. But as soon as I click inside the text box to type it dissappear because of the "data-trigger="focus". How do I make the div intelligently not disappear on click inside it? Here is my html :

```
  <head><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></head>
<body><div><a class="BookAppButton" href="" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus">Click Here</a></div></body>
```

Here is my jquery :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.BookAppButton').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Button Clicked..");
});
$('.BookAppButton').popover({
        title : '',
        html : 'true',
    content:'<div style="border:black 2px solid"><p>Enter name : <input type="text"></input></p></div>'
    });
});
```

This is my jsfiddle link :
     http://jsfiddle.net/3g3o4xhw/

I am at my wits end.. please help.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

Clicks on the popover are hiding that popover because they are stealing the browser's focus. As soon as the button loses focus, the popover will be hidden (because we've set `data-trigger="focus"`).

**To address exact question you asked:**

> prevent the popover div for hiding on clicking inside it for twitter bootstrap “dismissible popover”(data-trigger=“focus”)?

The simplest way to fix this is to prevent clicks inside the popover from stealing focus by:

- Adding an event listener to catch clicks inside the popover
- Calling `preventDefault()` on the caught event

This will stop the focus from being stolen, and so stop the popover from being closed.

Note: We need to add the event listener on `mousedown` rather than `click`, because that is when the focus is set by the browser.

A more in-depth explanation of why we use `mousedown` and `preventDefault()` can be found on this StackOverflow answer: 
[Prevent firing focus event when clicking on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735764/prevent-firing-focus-event-when-clicking-on-div#8736218)

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

$('body')
  .on('mousedown', '.popover', function(e) {
    console.log("clicked inside popover")
    e.preventDefault()
  });
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible" data-content="Clicks in here won't steal focus">
    Dismissible popover
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have highcharts inside a bootstrap popover, and it doesn't close on a mouse click, but it starting closing on tap (mobile) recently (even though I didn't change the code). This method worked perfectly to bring it back to desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me, you can dismiss the popover upon any condition by calling **preventDefault()** method.

```
var closePopOver=true;
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true,
        title: '',
        content: function () {
            return 'Your Html Here';
        }
    }).on('hide.bs.popover', function (hideEvent) {
        if (!closePopOver) {
            hideEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `tigger: 'click'`.

```
$('.BookAppButton').popover({
        title : '',
        html : 'true',
    trigger: 'click',
    content:'<div style="border:black 2px solid"><p>Enter name : <input type="text"></input></p></div>'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
data-trigger="focus"
```

you should use

```
data-trigger="'focus'"
```

for AngularUI Bootstrap version 2.0 and above.