# Bootstrap3 popover data-trigger=focus closing popup when clicking on <select> input within popup

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using a bootstrap popover and have a `<select>` field inside of the popover in order for the user to change languages.

If they click outside the popover, I want it to disappear, so I am using the `data-trigger="focus"` attribute within the `<a>` tag to accomplish this.

However, if they click on the `<select>` drop down menu, the popover disappears before they can click a language.

Below is a bootply for your reference - any help is much appreciated.

http://www.bootply.com/SEM4ophIhx

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

$(function () {
    $('[rel="popover"]').popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            var clone = $($(this).data('popover-content')).clone(true).removeClass('hide');
            return clone;
        }
    }).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" role="button" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" rel="popover" data-popover-content="#profilesettingsaction">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
</a>
    <div id="profilesettingsaction" class="hide">                               
      <ul>
        <li>
          <select name="language">
            <option value="">العربية: الإمارات العربية المتحدة</option>
            <option value="">中国</option>
            <option value="">中國</option>
            <option value="">Nederlands: Nederland</option>
            <option value="">English: United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="" selected="">Language: English</option>
            <option value="">Français: France</option>
            <option value="">Italiano: l'Italia</option>
            <option value="">日本語：日本</option>
            <option value="">Português: Portugal</option>
            <option value="">Español: México</option>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>                                
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found a way to do this](http://mattlockyer.com/2013/04/08/close-a-twitter-bootstrap-popover-when-clicking-outside/)

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

You simply catch click events on the body and check if the target is a child of your popover. However this is really slow.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you misused the attribute data-trigger, you should have specified click, not focus.

Here it is working: http://www.bootply.com/5gXiitMup1

I added the code to handle popover closing whenever a language is selected.

Hope it is useful.

Comment: Thanks, this is great info, but I still want the user to be able to click outside the popover and for it to go away, while still being able to select a language from the drop down.

When the user clicks a language, the page will reload anyways to show the new copy, in turn collapsing the popup anyways.

This guys is having the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648587/how-to-prevent-the-popover-div-for-hiding-on-clicking-inside-it-for-twitter-boot

Comment: seems it's not possible at this time, I've tried many paths, but you could implement a similar thing in JQuery code and program your custom behaviour, i'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks, ya I tried a bunch of things too and was hoping I was missing something the community had experienced before.