# Contenteditable div - How the button click event differs from other elements click events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to insert text at the current cursor position in the content editable div by clicking on some other element . This works perfect if I click on button , but not working with any other element . I mean for the button it is inserting at the cursor position , but for any other element clicks it is always adding the starting position of the div . Below is an example which includes  Button click and DIV click( It is not working for any other tag ) . Is there any difference between these two clicks ? How can I make DIV click exactly like a button click . Please note I am not using JQUERY ( But if there is any solution with VUEJS I am fine ) . Thank You .

Here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jwvha/2727/

```js
function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
  document.getElementById('pre').focus();
  var sel, range, html;
  sel = window.getSelection();
  range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents();
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
  range.insertNode(textNode);
  range.setStartAfter(textNode);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

div {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Editor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div contenteditable id="pre">
    Update text Here . This is contenteditable div
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" onClick="insertTextAtCursor('TEXT')" value="Click here to insert text above"> ( This button inserts text at the cursors current positions)
  </div>
  <div onClick="insertTextAtCursor('TEXT')">
    <b>Click here to insert in the above  contenteditable div </b> ( This won't insert at the current position , but always at the position 1)
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons do not gain focus on click unlike many other elements. As you are relying on focus in your function, after a successful `click` event (which consists of `mouseup` + `mousedown`) that bubbles up the DOM tree, your focus is being set on the div first. You can avoid this by either listening to mousedown events and calling `event.preventDefault()` or simply trigger your function before `click` is fired, i.e. `onmousedown`.

Here is [an answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8736218/7753036) that explains everything pretty well.

```js
var prevented = document.getElementById("prevented");
prevented.addEventListener('mousedown', event => event.preventDefault());

function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
  document.getElementById('pre').focus();
  var sel, range, html;
  sel = window.getSelection();
  range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents();
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
  range.insertNode(textNode);
  range.setStartAfter(textNode);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

div {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Editor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div contenteditable id="pre">
    Update text Here . This is contenteditable div
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" onClick="insertTextAtCursor('TEXT')" value="Click here to insert text above"> ( This button inserts text at the cursors current positions)
  </div>
  <div onClick="insertTextAtCursor('TEXT')" id="prevented">
    <b>Click here to insert in the above  contenteditable div </b> ( This won't insert at the current position , but always at the position 1)
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem, it just sets it ONCE before losing focus.

Comment: I was just giving a basic idea of the root of the problem. I've updated my answer with a basic event listener.

Comment: Thank You for your answer and the solution . This is really helpful .  I have to check if this can be implemented for emoji-mart-vue . Thanks again