# Insert text in editable div when another div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I have an editable `div` and I want to insert some text when another `div` is clicked, using `document.execCommand`. When I use a `button`, it works properly, but it doesn't work when a clickable `div` is used.

```
<!-- When I click this, it works -->
<button on:click={e => document.execCommand("insertText", false, "Some text")}>Inser text</button>

<!-- When I click this, it doesn't -->
<div on:click={e => document.execCommand("insertText", false, "Some text")}>Inser text</div>

<div contenteditable="true" />
```

I suspect it's a focus issue. I have tried calling `e.preventDefault()` but it doesn't work either.

It's not relevant but I'm using Svelte.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735764/prevent-firing-focus-event-when-clicking-on-div).

Basically, `mousedown` event should be used, instead of `click`.

In my case, it looks like this:

```
<div on:mousedown={e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, "Some text");
}>Inser text</div>
```